# strapi: Server wasn't able to start properly TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: reactjs, strapi

please how to resolve this problem :(

```
[2021-11-12T10:48:02.075Z] debug ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
[2021-11-12T10:48:02.076Z] error TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.values (<anonymous>)
    at Object.load (/home/mondher/plateforme/node_modules/strapi-database/lib/connector-registry.js:17:39)
    at DatabaseManager.initialize (/home/mondher/plateforme/node_modules/strapi-database/lib/database-manager.js:32:21)
    at Strapi.load (/home/mondher/plateforme/node_modules/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:299:19)
    at async Strapi.start (/home/mondher/plateforme/node_modules/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:158:9)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reproduce this error, rename or delete on of your files in the config folder, basically Strapi wasn't able to be all required configurations during startup - *Strapi should should a better job with logging*

Go their documentation and check if your config files match to what has been mentioned. I was using using Strapi V3 and [here](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/configurations.html) is the link I used.